# How to convert an object to Unicode in a way that works in both py2 and py3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to fix a bug in a Python library that happens when I try to convert an object to string.

```
str(obj)      # fails on py2 when the object return unicode
unicode(obj)  # works perfectly on py2 but fails on py3
```

Comment: What do you need to have, a Unicode value or an encoded bytes value? Does it differ between Python 2 and 3? What types can `obj` be?

Answer (score 0):

Since `unicode` is turned into the standard `str` type (with `str` turning into `bytes`) when moving from Python 2 to Python 3, one way to get around this issue in a way that runs in both Python 2 and 3 is to define `unicode` to be equivalent to `str` when running in Python 3.  This is generally done in libraries that need to support both these Python versions, examples can be found at [`oauthlib.common`](https://github.com/idan/oauthlib/blob/0.6.3/oauthlib/common.py#L60) or [`requests.compat`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/v2.3.0/requests/compat.py) (which includes an even more comprehensive compatibility layer).  Any calls internally to that library will reference that type whenever they need to ensure they need `bytes` or `str` when checking for invariants/assertions, casting and such.

Answer (score 0):

Django has a neat solution for this, they provide their users with a decorator which can be applied to the class.

```
def python_2_unicode_compatible(klass):
    """
    A decorator that defines __unicode__ and __str__ methods under Python 2.
    Under Python 3 it does nothing.

    To support Python 2 and 3 with a single code base, define a __str__ method
    returning text and apply this decorator to the class.
    """
    if six.PY2:
        if '__str__' not in klass.__dict__:
            raise ValueError("@python_2_unicode_compatible cannot be applied "
                             "to %s because it doesn't define __str__()." %
                             klass.__name__)
        klass.__unicode__ = klass.__str__
        klass.__str__ = lambda self: self.__unicode__().encode('utf-8')
    return klass
```

It depends on the python library six though. (Please pay attention to the code license!)

Comment: This only applies to *producing* a string; you are expected to define a `__str__` method that produces a Unicode return value, and for Python 2, that method is moved over to the `__unicode__` method and a suitable `__str__` producing a byte string is given. That's of no use to the OP however.

Comment: @MartijnPieters dammit, you're right. I assumed he wants to implement the __str__ method in a backwards compatible way in a class he wrote.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `%s` formatting to get a unicode() in 2.7 and str() in 3.5, as long as you import `unicode_literals` which everyone should be doing anyway.

I've found this trick quite helpful and it doesn't need a compat library imported everywhere.

PY 2.7x

```
>>> from __future__ import unicode_literals
>>> "%s" % 32
u'32'  (<type 'unicode'>)
```

PY 3.5

```
>>> ("%s" % (42)).__class__
<class 'str'>
```

Adding this here since it was the first result that came up in google when I was looking for something other than `six.text_type(value)` or another compat library.